# Upgrade 2.2.4 to 2.2.5 SQL query error

Tags: magento2, product, database, magento2.2, sql

Good morning. I just upgraded from 2.2.4 and I get this template filter error in my home page:

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'at_featured_default.value' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT
>   DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
>   INNER JOIN catalog_category_product_index_store6 AS cat_index ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='6' AND
>   cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2' INNER JOIN
>   catalog_product_index_price AS price_index ON price_index.entity_id =
>   e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND
>   price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (((IFNULL(e.entity_id,
>   at_featured_default.value) IN ('1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
>   '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '21', '20')) ))`

I'm not sure if this query is in default Magento or if it's my theme creating this issue, but I don't know how to find where this query is originating. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried running full reindex ?

Comment: I did try to reindex, unfortunately it's not chainging anything.

Comment: it could not found `at_featured_default` in column so maybe it removed or not full query in your question.

Comment: Indeed it looks like this query is not correct. Any idea on how to find it in the code and change it?

Answer (score 0):

So, this won't fix the actual problem but it will allow the page to load until it can be fixed...

I had the same issue and it was only on the homepage where I had a "featured products" widget. Delete the widget and the page should load (after cache:clean|flush).